# How can I apply Dockerfile multistage approach with Selenium and Firefox?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox, alpine-linux

I'm trying to split my Dockerfile into multistage approach to reduce size. I'm using Selenium and firefox but copying from base image does not work.

```
find / -name firefox
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
/usr/bin/firefox

which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.4-alpine
COPY --from=base_image /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
COPY --from=base_image /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=base_image /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox
COPY --from=base_image /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
COPY --from=base_image /project /project
```

selenium.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
#options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox"
#options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox/firefox-bin"
#options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
service = webdriver.FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```

None of three diff bin paths works

How can i copy firefox files from base to final image and make Selenium works well?

Comment: Using a multi-stage build like this only saves space if you have some tool like a C compiler that you need to build your application, but not to eventually run it.  If you need to copy every part of some program from an earlier stage to a later one, it'll take up the same pace.  I wouldn't be surprised to see you're missing parts like C shared libraries or Javascript support files in this manual-copy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fairly light weight Docker image using this. It's hard to get more minimal than this. Cherry-picking dependencies from one stage to another will not be worth the pain.

Firefox will be installed onto your `PATH`, so there's no need to specify this path explicitly.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11.4-alpine

RUN apk add firefox && \
    pip install selenium==4.18.1

COPY selenium-firefox.py .

ENV MOZ_HEADLESS=1

CMD python3 selenium-firefox.py
```

`selenium-firefox.py` (A simple test script.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("http://google.com/")

print(driver.title)

driver.quit()
```

[image]